# How to change default value react-i18next (in localstorage)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-i18next

I`am use backend and language detector, but:

In localstorage is written **I18nextLng** with the value **en-US**, how to make default value is **I18nextLng** with the value **En**

*init* and other settings - default documentation

```
.init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I never used the language detector, but the way I set the default language is to set the **lng** key, and have **resources** obj

```
const resources = {
  en: { translation: {...} },
  fr: { translation: {...} }
}

.init({
    resources,
    lng: 'fr' // this is the default language. Try to put this
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
    },
})
```

Comment: If reload page, then select language is remove and is set default language.
But thx for answer

Comment: What you can do, is at the beginning of the app. Set in the local storage the default language. then you put `lng: window.localStorage.defaultLanguage`